# Adding label over multiple labels in java

Tags: java, swing

I have added multiple labels (*boxes*) on JFrame in the form of a grid. Now I want to add a label (*ladder*) over some of the labels in the grid, for this I am doing something like this:

```
for(int i=0, x=0; i<10; i++,x+=50) {
    for(int j=0, y=0; j<10; j++,y+=50) {
        box[i][j] = new JLabel(j);
        box[i][j].setOpaque(true);
        box[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);   
        box[i][j].setBounds(x, y, 50,50);
        board.add(box[i][j]);
    }
}

ladder.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 200);
ladder.setOpaque(true);
board.add(ladder);
```

But this code does not adds ladder over boxes. So kindly tell how can I add ladder label over boxes.

Comment: What is the layout manager of `board` ?

Comment: Use [JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) Luke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the [JLayeredPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html) from your `JFrame` to achieve this.

Just put the board on the back layer, and the ladder on the front layer.

Here is an example, close to your actual code :

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JPanel board = new JPanel();

    board.setLayout(null);
    board.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);

    for (int i = 0, x = 0; i < 10; i++, x += 50) {
        for (int j = 0, y = 0; j < 10; j++, y += 50) {
            JLabel lab = new JLabel("" + j);
            lab.setOpaque(true);
            lab.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            lab.setBounds(x, y, 50, 50);
            board.add(lab);
        }
    }

    JLabel ladder = new JLabel();
    ladder.setBackground(Color.RED);
    ladder.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 200);
    ladder.setOpaque(true);

    JLayeredPane pane = frame.getLayeredPane();

    pane.add(ladder, new Integer(2)); // front
    pane.add(board, new Integer(1));  // back

    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Some more information here : [How to Use Layered Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)